# Get links from HTML after a certain title

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

See this HTML code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="fixedfonts">
            <a href="A.pdf">LINK1</a>
        </p>

        <h2>Results</h2>

        <p class="fixedfonts">
            <a href="B.pdf">LINK2</a>
        </p>

        <p class="fixedfonts">
            <a href="C.pdf">LINK3</a>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It contains 3 links. However I need to retrieve only the links after the title `Results`

I am using python with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

# at this point html contains the code as string

# parse the HTML file
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.replace('\n', ''), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()  # rip it out

links = list()
for link in soup:
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        links.append(link['href'].replace('%20', ' '))

print(links)
```

With the the presented code I get all the links in the document, but as I said I only need those that are after the `Results` tag/title.

Guidance is appreciated

Comment: `[i['href'] for i in soup.select('.fixedfonts a')]`

Comment: In the dummy example this works, but in the real life html it doesn't since all come inside the fixedfonts class

Comment: How does killing all scripts and style elements help?

Comment: I guess it is innocuous, but I'll remove it and see

Comment: Add a link to the actual site

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that using the [`find_all_next()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next):

```
results = soup.find("h2", text="Results")
for link in results.find_all_next("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <html>
...     <body>
...         <p class="fixedfonts">
...             <a href="A.pdf">LINK1</a>
...         </p>
... 
...         <h2>Results</h2>
... 
...         <p class="fixedfonts">
...             <a href="B.pdf">LINK2</a>
...         </p>
... 
...         <p class="fixedfonts">
...             <a href="C.pdf">LINK3</a>
...         </p>
...     </body>
... </html>"""
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> results = soup.find("h2", text="Results")
>>> for link in results.find_all_next("a"):
...     print(link.get("href"))
... 
B.pdf
C.pdf
```

Comment: the `results` contains `None`. Not sure why but the find function is not working

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera ah, could be because of the extra chars around the text, try 'soup.find("h2", text=re.compile("Results"))'..and u would need to import re, of course. Hope that helps.

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera well, works on the sample u've provided, could u show what your real HTML is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Split the html data into two parts, before and after the "Results" Then use the one after to process it:

```
data = html.split("Results")
need = data[1]
```

So just implement that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
data = html.split("Results")
need = data[1]
soup = BeautifulSoup(need.replace('\n', ''), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))
```

Comment: I just tried and Beautifulsoup does not get any link because the html is "broken" by splitting the file in two. Although at first it looks like a great solution

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera Senpai, use similar implementation, but instead of using that string that was formed by splitting to process it with beautifulsoup, find all the links as you are doing and loop through those links and check if the link is a substring of the splitted string using if and else statements.

Comment: I cannot use that solution since in my practical problem some links are repeated. That is actually why I need to take the links that are below the results tag.

Comment: You should be able to check for repititions in list? usually result responses gives one of each link and there might be a repeated link above results, so you just have to ensure, only one is there, or if in some cases if there are more than one links after results simply check how many times it occurs after results using the method i presented. And for even more confirmation you can check how many times it repeats before results too.

Answer (score -1):

Tested and seemed to work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

html = '''<html>
<body>
    <p class="fixedfonts">
        <a href="A.pdf">LINK1</a>
    </p>

    <h2>Results</h2>

    <p class="fixedfonts">
        <a href="B.pdf">LINK2</a>
    </p>

    <p class="fixedfonts">
        <a href="B.pdf">LINK2</a>
    </p>

    <p class="fixedfonts">
        <a href="C.pdf">LINK3</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>'''

# at this point html contains the code as string

# parse the HTML file
dat = html.split("Result")
need = dat[1]
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.replace('\n', ''), parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'))

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()  # rip it out

links = list()
for link in soup:
    if link.has_attr('href'):
         links.append(link['href'].replace('%20', ' '))

n_links = list()
for i in set(links):
    if need.count(i) > 0:
        for x in range(1, need.count(i) + 1):
            n_links.append(i)

print(n_links)
```